# Agenda scheduler not running

Tags: node.js, cron, agenda

I am trying to schedule a one-time job on a specific date, however, the callback never gets called once the date is reached. The job gets created and added to the collection. Not sure what I am doing wrong. Using [agenda](https://github.com/agenda/agenda)

```
const agenda = new Agenda({
  db: {address: '...', collection: 'agendaJobs'},
  useUnifiedTopology: true
});

agenda.on('ready', async () => {
   agenda.define("hello", 
    { priority: "high", concurrency: 20 },
    async (job) => {
      console.log("hello");
    });
});

async function start() {
  agenda.processEvery('1 second');
  await agenda.start();
  await agenda.schedule("in 10 seconds", "hello");
}

start();
```

Comment: move all lines of code outside of ready event callback  in another anonymous `async` function, and define your job after agenda instance has been created

Comment: from Agenda documentation `Agenda will emit a ready event when properly connected to the database. It is safe to call agenda.start() without waiting for this event, as this is handled internally`

Comment: Updated my code and it still does not work

Comment: move `hello` define outside of ready event

Comment: No luck, that still didn't run the job

Comment: I am looking at my database lookup logs and it doesn't even look like its performing any db operation to loop up the collection

Comment: I have posted answer please check.

Answer (score 1):

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "testing",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "agenda": "^4.2.1"
  }
}
```

**index.js**

```js
const Agenda = require('agenda');

const mongoConnectionString = "mongodb://127.0.0.1/agenda";
const agenda = new Agenda({
  db: {address: mongoConnectionString},
  useUnifiedTopology: true
});

agenda.on('ready', async () => {
  console.log('connected');
});

agenda.define("hello", { priority: "high", concurrency: 20 }, async (job) => {
  console.log("hello");
});

(async function() {
  agenda.processEvery('1 second');
  await agenda.start();
  await agenda.schedule("in 10 seconds", "hello");
})();
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If your agenda scheduler is not running, check if your database collection for the agenda jobs is empty or not.